# java fork/join mergesort updated for easy duplication

Tags: java, mergesort, fork-join

I've created a complete, runnable example that reproduces the error of not having my list actually sorted by mergesort. What is printed to the console is 22,
22,
22,
1,
1,
1,
-2,
-2,
-2,
1,
22,
-2,
1,
22,
-2. So it appears that mergesort never affects the second half of the list, and the first half is only sorted because insertSort is successfully called. Any help and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

```
package threadedmergesort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class ThreadedMergeSort implements Comparator<Integer>{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Integer> toSort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);
         toSort.add(1);  
         toSort.add(22);
         toSort.add(-2);

         ThreadedMergeSort.sort(toSort, 0, toSort.size()-11);
         for (Integer e: toSort){
                System.out.println(e);
                }
    }

    public static void sort (ArrayList<Integer> inputComp){
        sort(inputComp, 0, inputComp.size()-1);
    }
    public static void sort (ArrayList<Integer> inputComp, int low, int high){
        if (high-low< SIZE_LIMIT){
            insertionSort(inputComp, low, high);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList(inputComp.size());
        pool.invoke(new SortTask(inputComp, temp, low, high));
        System.out.println("pool.invoke");
    }

    static class SortTask extends RecursiveAction{
        ArrayList<Integer> inputComp;
        ArrayList<Integer> temp;
        int low;
        int high;

        public SortTask(ArrayList<Integer> inputComp, ArrayList<Integer> temp, int low, int high){
            this.inputComp=inputComp;
            this.temp=temp;
            this.low=low;
            this.high=high;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute(){
            if (high-low<SIZE_LIMIT){
                insertionSort(inputComp, low, high);
                return;
            }
            int middle = (low + high)/2;
            invokeAll(new SortTask(inputComp, temp, low, middle), new SortTask(inputComp, temp, middle+1, high));
            merge(inputComp, temp, low, middle, high);
        }  
    }
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer c1, Integer c2){
        if (c1> c2){
            return -1;
        }
        if (c1 > c2){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void arrayListCopy(ArrayList<Integer> src, int srcPos, ArrayList<Integer> dest, int destPos, int length){
        for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
            dest.set(destPos+i, src.get(srcPos+i));
        }
    }
    private static void merge(ArrayList<Integer> inputComp1, ArrayList<Integer> inputComp2, int low, int middle, int high){
        ThreadedMergeSort sort = new ThreadedMergeSort();
        if(sort.compare(inputComp1.get(middle), inputComp1.get(middle+1)) <0){
            return;
        }
        arrayListCopy(inputComp1, low, inputComp2, low, middle-low+1);
        int i = low;
        int j = middle+1;
        int k = low;
        while(k < j && j <= high){
            if(sort.compare(inputComp2.get(i),inputComp1.get(j)) <= 0){
                inputComp1.set(k++, inputComp2.get(i++));
            }
            else{
                inputComp1.set(k++,inputComp1.get(j++));
            }
        }
        arrayListCopy(inputComp2, i, inputComp1, k, j-k);
    }

    private static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputComp, int low, int high){
        ThreadedMergeSort sort = new ThreadedMergeSort();
        for(int i = low+1; i<=high; i++){
            int j = i;
            Integer entry = inputComp.get(j);
            while(low<j && sort.compare(entry, inputComp.get(j-1))< 0){
                inputComp.set(j,inputComp.get(j-1));
                --j;
            }
            inputComp.set(j,entry);
        }
    }
    private static final ForkJoinPool pool =  new ForkJoinPool();
    private static final int SIZE_LIMIT = 8;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to implement your own sort method? Arrays.sort and Arrays.parallelSort are usually the best solution.

Comment: I'm utilizing an ArrayList, so I cant't use Array.sort. And I need an ArrayList so I can dynamically add new entries simply, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: In this case, you can use Collections.sort or convert list to array, sort it and create new list from sorted array.

Comment: I think I may do that, but I really want to understand where I went wrong in this implementation

Answer (score 0):

It's doing what you asked:

```
ThreadedMergeSort.sort(toSort, 0, toSort.size()-11);
```

Did you mean 1 or 11?

Comment: I added that because if the size is any larger than the SIZE_LIMIT, it returns an IndexOutOfBoundsException. That may the true problem with my code. You can reproduce this by removing the 11 or changing it to a 1. The former will return "Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 15", while the latter will return the same with index and size being 0.

Comment: what line do you get the index out of bounds error?

Comment: why is SIZE_LIMIT set to 8?

Comment: It's set to 8 so that it stops dividing when the size is 8, at which point it does InsertionSort and starts merging the lists together again. I'm not sure exactly where I'm getting the error, but [here's](http://gyazo.com/6a3ad133a95a18dc47d9603fe442c02f) the stack trace

Comment: Setting size-11 is simply masking your real problem and causing your list to only be semi sorted. The real problem is with construction of new SortTask(inputComp, temp, low, high), inside pool.invoke. Maybe change your code and ask a different question. Using size-11 simply means you never try this construction so your SortTask is never instantiated or executed